# Backbone/javascript - confused by 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, this

In the following backbone scripts, I tried to change a collection in a view click event.

```
var StudentView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
      console.log("create  student items view");
      this.collection.bind('add',this.render,this); 
              this.collection.bind('remove',this.render,this);
    },
    render : function(){


    },
    events :{
        "click ":"select_students"
    },
    select_students: function(){
        this.collection.reset([]);
        _.each(students.models, function(m) {
            if(m.get('name')=="Daniel"){
                this.collection.add(m);
            }
        });                         
    }

});

var students_view = new  StudentView({el:$("#student_table"),collection:selected_students});
```

I got this error [image]

How should I call "this.collection" in the code?

Comment: I think the view has information of the model, but neither the model nor the view have a pointer to the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change you `select_students` to

```
select_students: function(){
    var self = this;
    this.collection.reset([]);
    _.each(students.models, function(m) {
        if(m.get('name')=="Daniel"){
            self.collection.add(m);
        }
    });                         
}
```

The problem is that in JavaScript, the `this` context is lost in inner functions (like the one you pass to `_.each`) so the general pattern is to save a reference outside of that (`self`) and then use that in the inner function.

Comment: This is a 'scope' issue, inside of _.each(, function(){...}) 'this' doesn't refer to the parent object because it is nested inside of an anonymous function. If you place a console.log(this); before the line thats causing the error you'll see that 'this' isn't referencing what you think it is. That answer above is a workaround by creating a variable as a reference to 'this'. Another popular version is 'var me = this;

Comment: or you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using underscore's each() function, backbone collections can be iterated on directly, and can take a context to define what the 'this' variable refers to (passed as the second argument to each below).

So the best way to do this is to:

```
select_students: function(){
    this.collection.reset([]);
    students.each(function(m) {
        if(m.get('name')=="Daniel"){
            this.collection.add(m);
        }
    }, this);                         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using a reference at all, utilizing Backbone's collection [filter](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) method.

```
select_students: function () {
    this.collection.reset(students.filter(function (student) {
        return student.get('name') == 'Daniel';
    });
}
```